# What are the border procedures like when flying Istanbul-Hopa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey, domestic-travel, turkish-airlines

Through Turkish Airlines, it is possible to buy a domestic ticket from Istanbul-Atatürk to Hopa, whereby you fly from Istanbul to Batumi in Georgia, then take a "sterile" bus across the border to Hopa, without clearing Georgian immigration.

Obviously, since this is a flight to Batumi after all, and you can't segregate domestic and international pax on the plane, you will clear immigration at Atatürk, which is also stated on Turkish's website

My questions are:

1. Do you clear immigration in Hopa? If so, where?
2. When clearing immigration at Atatürk and (if at all) Hopa, do you get stamped in/out, given that you have to show your boarding pass? In other words, do I get an exit stamp on the migration card at Atatürk, and get a new migration card with an entry stamp in Hopa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Russian blogger (Alexander Lapshin) [wrote](http://puerrtto.livejournal.com/308278.html) two extensive [blog posts](http://puerrtto.livejournal.com/575748.html) about this very flight, which gives a precise answer to your questions.

> Do you clear immigration in Hopa? If so, where?

No, you do not clear Turkish (or Georgian) immigration anywhere during this flight. When arriving to Batumi you get onto a special bus which takes you to Hopa and you don't meet any border officials during the journey.

> When clearing immigration at Atatürk and (if at all) Hopa, do you get stamped in/out, given that you have to show your boarding pass?

No, you don't. It's treated as a domestic flight, even though the technical airport of arrival is in Batumi. Back in 2006 Turkey and Georgia [have signed a special agreement](http://www.civil.ge/eng/article.php?id=12432) which allows Turkey to have a virtual airport in their North-Eastern provinces.

Comment: Hmm, the first blog contains a picture of stamps from Atatürk and Hopa. It's from 2012 though, things might've changed since

Comment: @Crazydre apparently you do get a stamp on the way back